# Share link via Intent from PreferenceScreen

Tags: android, xml, android-intent, share, preferencescreen

I am using this code to display app on play store:

```
    <PreferenceScreen android:title="Please rate and comment" >
        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:data="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chovanec.square" />
    </PreferenceScreen>
```

but also I want to share this link. How can I do it? This do not work:

```
    <PreferenceScreen android:title="Please rate and comment" >
        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.SHARE"
            android:data="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chovanec.square" />
    </PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-implement-a-share-intent/

You can  try to download plugin from github.